# JavaScript - Expand/Collapsing Issue While Using Multiple Classes

Tags: javascript

There a lot of similar questions and I've looked at a lot of them, but couldn't figure out or find one that addressed this problem.

The issue is I'm trying to apply event listeners to a particular class (success for the most part), and each of those classes have their own elements with a separate class.

```
group.addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
```

`group` is a class which will have the click event.

```
    function toggle() {
        var contents = this.getElementsByClassName('content');     

        for (i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {

            if (contents[i].style.display == "block") {
                contents[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                contents[i].style.display = "block";
            }
        }      
    }
```

`contents` is another class nested within `group`. There will be a lot of `contents`, but only a handful of `group`.

Using `.addEventListener` works, but the `click` event for it expands/collapses every `contents`, not just the ones under that particular `group` which is what I want.  I click on any one of the `group` and all of the `contents` on the page will expand/collapse.  How can I fix this?  By the way, these are just snippets of the code (it's a lot to post).  I tried to use `this` to provide scope, but I'm just doing it wrong since it's producing the same results anyway.  Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

More about the HTML

```
group.innerHTML += String.format("<div class='group' style='display: block;'>" +
                            "<h3 style='display: inline-block; color: #000; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;'>{0}</h3>" +
                            "<img src='https:\/\/my.blah.com\/_layouts\/15\/images\/ecbarw.png' style='margin: 5px;' alt='Click to expand-collapse.' />" +
                            "{1}</div>", trimmedKey, groups[key]);

group.addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
```

I'm using this for a SharePoint web part.  It's within display templates so that's why there's a lot of unrelated code to post, but I'll include the relevant HTML for `group` and `contents`.

```
var content = String.format('<div class="content" style="display: none; margin: 30px 0px;"><span id="{0}" class="ms-srch-item-title">' +
                '<h3 class="ms-srch-ellipsis">{1}</h3>' +
            '</span>' +
            '<span style="margin-right: 10px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Assigned To: </span>{2}</span>' +
            '<span style="margin-right: 10px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Due Date: </span>{3}</span>' + 
            '<span style="margin-right: 10px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Task Status: </span>{4}</span></div>', $htmlEncode(id + Srch.U.Ids.title), titleHtml, assignedTo, dueDate, status);

search.Grouping.push(grouping, content);
```

The `content` is getting pushed to a function (not shown here) that sorts them into groups.  The `groups[key]` is basically the same thing as `content`.

Comment: Can you clarify what your HTML structure basically looks like and which elements are expected to be affected and which are actually affected? Do you need to select two classes at the same time? Then use something like `document.getElementsByClassName('content anotherClass')`.

Comment: Is the class name `content` or `contents` because I see you have used `content` in the code but in the question you have mentioned `contents`?

Comment: I edited the post to include more information.  Xufox - I do need two classes at the same time, but I never tried this: `document.getElementsByClassName('content anotherClass')` so I will try that.  And AKS - content and contents are technically two different things.  `content` is the class while `contents` is the array, but it's referring to the same information.

Comment: Please checkout this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvpoo8de/), it works as expected.

Comment: The jsfiddle isn't working for me...I'm clicking around and nothing.

Comment: Here is a new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wvpoo8de/1/. Please try this.

Comment: It works!  Thank you so much!! If you submit an answer, I'll mark it (can't upvote comments yet).

Comment: @LaLaLottie Glad that it worked. I have added the code as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why it is not working in your case but I have prepared a simple demo for you here:

```js
// get all the elements with class 'group'
var groups = document.getElementsByClassName('group');

// add click event listener to each group
for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i ++)
  groups[i].addEventListener("click", toggle, false);

// function to toggle group contents
function toggle() {
  // get all the elements within this group with class 'content'
  var contents = this.getElementsByClassName('content');     

  // if the content is visible then hide it and vice-versa 
  for (i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    if (contents[i].style.display == "block") {
      contents[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
      contents[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }      
}
```

```css
.content {
  display: None;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.group {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
Group1
  <div class="content another">
  Group 1 Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="content another">
  Group 1 Content 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
Group2
  <div class="content another">
  Group 2 Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="content another">
  Group 2 Content 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's collapsing group content when content is clicked? OP is it fine?

Comment: Well, I agree that it does however it is not a complete answer but just an idea around which OP could improve his code. If you look at the comments I first added a JS fiddle but OP asked that I should add it as an answer.

Comment: Right i'm just asking;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Yes, it works great for me.  I did modify it a little in my code, but the same principle was used.